# Unir tabela usando uma SubQuery

Tags: oracle, join

Tenho 3 tabelas: `inscricaoaluno`, `inscricaoescola` e `prova`, com as seguintes estruturas:

**PROVA**

> IDPROVA | DESCPROVA | TIPO | QTDEMAX

**INSCRICAOESCOLA**

> PROFESSOR | ESCOLA(IDESCOLA) | DTINSCRICAO | IDPROVA

**INSCRICAOALUNO**

> ALUNO(IDALUNO) | ESCOLA | DTINSCRICAO | IDPROVA

De acordo com o `tipo` da prova, 'COLETIVO' ou 'INDIVIDUAL' irei pegar todas escolas inscritas e/ou todos alunos inscritos, pra isso gostaria de fazer uma query pra pegar somente as quantidades...

Estou tentando fazer o seguinte:

```
select * from prova p 
left join (
    case when p.tipo='COLETIVO' then 
        (SELECT ie.idProva, count(ie.idEscola) as qtde FROM inscricaoescola ie
        group by ie.idProva) 
    else 
        (SELECT ia.idProva, count(ia.idaluno) as qtde FROM inscricaoaluno ia
        group by ia.idProva)
    end as cont) 
on cont.idprova = p.idprova;
```

No console do SQLDeveloper aparece:

> "parêntese direito não encontrado"

Gostaria de saber se é possível criar um Query com essa estrutura que eu tentei fazer /\

```
left join (case {condição} then {subquery} else {outra_subquery} )
```

Se não houver gostaria de alguma luz de como posso fazer isso..

Comment: Se eu entendi bem, essas informações deveriam estar na projeção e não no JOIN, você quer o total de escolas ou de alunos que a prova vai ter certo?

Comment: Em Sql Serve dá pra fazer usando Querys dinâmicas.
Eles são montadas como strings e depois mando executar.

Answer (score 1):

Bom, não sei se é mesmo a solução ótima, porém eu consegui resolver...

Em vez de tentar criar essa lógica maluca de criar UM `left join` com um `case` dentro, eu criei dois `left's join`:

```
select * from prova p 
left join (SELECT ie.idProva, count(ie.idEscola) as qtde FROM inscricaoescola ie
        group by ie.idProva) contE on cont.idprova = p.idprova
left join
        (SELECT ia.idProva, count(ia.idaluno) as qtde FROM inscricaoaluno ia
        group by ia.idProva) contA on cont.idprova = p.idprova;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sobre a mensagem de erro:

> "parêntese direito não encontrado"

O problema é ficou falando o alias da tabela temporária criada.

```
select * from prova p 
left join (
    case when p.tipo='COLETIVO' then 
        (SELECT ie.idProva, count(ie.idEscola) as qtde FROM inscricaoescola ie
        group by ie.idProva) 
    else 
        (SELECT ia.idProva, count(ia.idaluno) as qtde FROM inscricaoaluno ia
        group by ia.idProva)
    end)  as cont '<<<<<<<<<<< 
on cont.idprova = p.idprova;
```

Sobre sua intenção com a estrutura buscada:

```
left join (case {condição} then {subquery} else {outra_subquery} )
```

Definitivamente é uma péssima ideia. Imagine o super processamento que o Oracle terá que fazer para realizar esse `join`.

1. Terá que trazer todos os registros da tabela `Prova`, sem filtrar;
2. Para cada registro, realizar a operação do `Join` e criar uma nova tabela temporária;
3. Realizar um `Union` em todas as temporárias criadas para criar uma única tabela temporária para realizar o `Left Join`;
4. Executar o `Left Join` de todos os registro de `Prova` contra uma temporária, sem índice algum.
5. Executar o filtro no `Where` finalmente filtrando o que precisa;

No final, serão envolvidas inúmeras tabelas, para calcular:

> 1 (Prova) + (Qtd de registros em Prova) + 1 (Temp. após Union)

Ou seja, totalmente insano. Sem contar os custos de processamento para realizar os `count()` e `group by`. E outra, a ultima clausula `WHERE` *mata* os `LEFT JOIN`s. De uma revisada.

Segue uma proposta mais simples e direta. Não tenho como rodar aqui comigo, mas se não funcionar, faça pequenos ajustes e me avisa que atualizo a resposta.

```
SELECT P.*,
       COUNT(IE.IdEscola) OVER(PARTITION BY IE.IdProva) QtdeIE,
       COUNT(IA.IdAluno) OVER(PARTITION BY IA.IdAluno) QtdeIA
  FROM Prova p
  JOIN InscricaoEscola IE
    ON P.Tipo = 'COLETIVO' AND IE.IdProva = P.IdProva
  JOIN InscricaoAluno IA
    ON P.Tipo = 'INDIVIDUAL' AND IA.IdProva = P.IdProva
```

Veja mais sobre [COUNT OVER PARTITION BY](http://psoug.org/reference/analytic_functions.html#acnt).

Comment: Haha amigo, obrigado pela resposta, hoje nem me encontro na mesma empresa, então nem tenho como testar mais , só um detalhe, o processamento da query acabou ficando meio pesadinho mesmo, de uma tabela com uns 500 mil registros, levava uns 40 segundos para executar

Comment: Nossa, nem tinha visto as datas. Bom, se puder, marca como resposta então, pelo esforço. rs @MarceloBonifazio

Comment: Não por isso, relaxa na época eu não tinha muito tempo pra responder, e eu aceito caso você detalhe mais aqui na sua resposta a funcionalidade da sua query, tipo como funciona o over partition 

Comment: Aí fica como dica de como funciona, se futuramente mais alguém tiver esse problema

Comment: Eu já tinha colocado lá um link para saber mais. :)

Comment: Sim haha, mas acho que ficaria melhor se você puxasse um pouco da explicação do conteúdo aqui pra sua resposta